# MapStateToProps not being called after changing STATE in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx, mapstatetoprops

I have theses files :

numPadHandler (my reducer),
configureStore (my store),
TestRedux (my component, trying to use the store)
and my app file.

reducer :

```
    // store/reducers/numpadReducers/numpadHandler
    
    const initialState = { valueNumPad: "1" }
    
    function numpadHandler(state = initialState, action) {
        let nextState;
        
        switch(action.type) {
            case 'ADD_DIGIT':
                nextState = state;
                nextState.valueNumPad = nextState.valueNumPad + action.value;
    
                console.log("reducer new state : " + state.valueNumPad); 
                return nextState;
    
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    
    export default numpadHandler;
```

store :

```
    // store/configureStore

    import { createStore } from 'redux';
    import numpadHandler from './reducers/numpadReducers/numpadHandler';
    
    export default createStore(numpadHandler);
```

component :

```
    // components/TestRedux
    
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import Button from './Button';
    
    const TestRedux = (props) => {
        const handleClick = () => {
            console.log("props value numpad : " + props.valueNumPad);
    
            const action = { type: "ADD_DIGIT", value: 5 }
            props.dispatch(action);
        }
        
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={handleClick} />
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        console.log("state : " + state.valueNumPad);
        return state
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestRedux);
```

app :

```
//...
render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={ Store }>
                <TestRedux />
            </Provider>
       );
}
```

I can't figure why when i click on the button, the reducer's state is changing but the function mapStateToProps isn't called again.

There is my console output after page load :

```
state : 1
```

After one click :

```
props value numpad : 1
reducer new state : 15
```

After two click :

```
props value numpad : 1
reducer new state : 155
```

Complete console output after 2 clicks :

```
state : 1
props value numpad : 1
reducer new state : 15
props value numpad : 1
reducer new state : 155
```

So you can see the action is happening and the reducer state is updating, but there is not update in component side !

Can you explain me why ?

RESOLVED :
Answer based on TLadd response :

My reducer code was wrong, this is the good way to code :

```
    case 'ADD_DIGIT':
      const nextState = { 
        ...state, 
        valueNumPad: state.valueNumPad + action.value
      };
      return nextState
```

Comment: You cannot mutate state in the reducer or redux will not detect the state has changed. [Here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) is some info on how to create a new state without mutating the old one. In your case you should do `return {...state, valueNumPad:state.valueNumPad+action.value}`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the reducer:

```
case 'ADD_DIGIT':
  nextState = state;
  nextState.valueNumPad = nextState.valueNumPad + action.value;
  console.log("reducer new state : " + state.valueNumPad); 
  return nextState;
```

Redux works off the assumption that [all state changes are handled immutably](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#why-is-immutability-required-by-redux). This choice allows it to use shallow equality checks when deciding which parts of your app need to re-render in response to an action being dispatched. In the above reducer case, you assign state to nextState and assign the new value directly to `nextState.valueNumPad`. Even though `nextState` is a new reference, it still refers to the original state as well and the result is a mutation of the original state.

The correct would to do this would be:

```
case 'ADD_DIGIT':
  const nextState = { 
    ...state, 
    valueNumPad: state.valueNumPad + action.value
  };
  return nextState
```

In this case, I'm making a copy of state using the spread notation `...state` and overwriting the `valueNumPad` value in that copy. The returned `nextState` is a new object and I did not mutate the old `state` object at all.